# Merge k lists of list of objects

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist, priority-queue, mergesort

I have multiple ArrayLists of objects, each with three parameters: time(in epoch milliseconds), stateId and customerId.
Each of these arraylists is sorted by time.
Now I need to merge the individually sorted arraylists and return one large list which will contain all the sorted lists.
I tried to use the merge sort approach as stated on this [website](http://www.lifeincode.net/programming/leetcode-merge-k-sorted-lists-java/).
However, the website is using a LinkNode which has a .next object which I do not have.
Is there any way I can implement the merge sort approach on this?

This is the object which the arraylists contain

```
public class Records {

    private String stateId;

    private long time;

    private String customerId;

}
```

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: Please edit question with relevant code snippets and what is not working correctly for you.  As it stands this question will most likely be closed for being too broad.

Comment: merge all arraylists means?

Comment: https://guava.dev/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Iterables.html#mergeSorted-java.lang.Iterable-java.util.Comparator-

Comment: *"Now I want to merge the individually sorted arraylists"* Then I suggest you start writing some code to get what you want.

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to implement merge-sort; In that case why not just look up some pseudo-code of the algorithm and follow along with that?

Answer (score 0):

You can treat the arraylists as arrays, using indexing to access the members, or you could treat the arraylists as lists, using list.get(0) (0 as an index) and list.remove(0) (0 as an index) to pop an element from a list (similar to a queue) and list.add() to append and element to a list (also similar to a queue).

Comment: This is what I did. Thank you.